# Cannot debug angular project in WebStorm due to crbug/1173575

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debugging, webstorm

My environment was working fine for weeks, until out of nowhere I started getting the following errors when trying to debug a project.  Nothing changed in the project, so I suspect something happened with Chrome.

The project builds and runs fine with `ng serve -o`, but the moment I try to run it in Debug mode, I get the following error:

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

Restarting the PC did not help.  Googling around for solutions only brings some solutions for VSCode, where you delete launch.settings file.  I use WebStorm, and the only two options in configuration are:

```
URL: https://localhost:4200
Browser: Chrome
```

Any pointers on getting to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my angular server not running.

Answer (score 1):

I had a support ticket with Jetbrains on this. According to them, you get two premade profiles, one for the framework of your choice and one for the JS debugger. This applies to both react and angular.

On my current project, I have "npm start" and "Debug Application". They told me to run NPM start and *leave it running*. Then start Debug Application.

The two things misleading on this are:

- all other Jetbrains product feature a single "debug" action, but Webstorm requires two parts to run
- the crbug/1173575 is extremely misleading, because it was never meant for public consumption, rather it comes from chrome and was meant for the UI to interpret.

The rationale behind this is the split nature of web services in general, that is reflected in the UI.